# access form, opposite of control source

Tags: forms, ms-access, version-control

I have a checkbox in a access form which get ticked depending on the control source. (checked if data is "-1", unchecked if 0). This is all working well but I need another checkbox that does the opposite. unchecked if data is -1 and checked if data is 0.

How can I do that?

[edit] I've read in https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3 that I can use the Iif function. Can I use this, to make a checkbox checked when another checkbox in my form is unchecked and vice versa..? I've tried this as a default value on checkbox2

```
=IIf([checkbox1.Value]=0, -1, 0)
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Why would you even need the second checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Won't work to set in Default Value property. Expression in Control Source property:

`=Not checkbox1`

But that will be an UNBOUND control. If you need to save the calculated value to a field that will require code - macro or VBA